# How to pipe the output of a function as the input of another function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

I guess this is a simple one but I'm unable to find the correct syntax or maybe the right method. Please help!

Objective: A function which returns the sum of of three numbers x, y and z. Using the sum as an input for another function which returns the average.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Java Script</title>

  <script>
    // Function for Sum
    function addition() {
      let numOne, numTwo, numThree, sum;
      numOne = parseInt(document.getElementById("firstNumber").value);
      numTwo = parseInt(document.getElementById("secondNumber").value);
      numThree = parseInt(document.getElementById("thirdNumber").value);
      sum = numOne + numTwo + numThree;
      document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sum;
    }

    // Function for average

    function average() {
      let numOne, numTwo, numThree, sum, avg;
      numOne = parseInt(document.getElementById("firstNumber").value);
      numTwo = parseInt(document.getElementById("secondNumber").value);
      numThree = parseInt(document.getElementById("thirdNumber").value);
      sum = numOne + numTwo + numThree;
      avg = sum / 3;
      document.getElementById("average").innerHTML = avg;
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <h1>Code</h1>

  <!-- Input  -->

  <label for="firstNumber">First Number: </label>
  <input type="text" id="firstNumber">

  <br><br>

  <label for="secondNumber">Second Number: </label>
  <input type="text" id="secondNumber">

  <br><br>

  <label for="thirdNumber">Third Number: </label>
  <input type="text" id="thirdNumber">

  <br><br>

  <!-- Output -->

  <label for="sum">Sum: </label>
  <p id="sum">Sum here! </p>

  <label for="average">Average: </label>
  <p id="average">Average here! </p>

  <!-- Buttons -->

  <input type="button" value="Sum" onclick="addition()">

  <input type="button" value="average" onclick="average()">

  <br><br><br>

</body>

</html>
```

The second function (average) could have used the output of the first function (addition) as the value for the sum (variable) instead of writing all the code over again!

Comment: You just need to return the value rather than setting the html

Answer (score 0):

You could add a return statement in the addition() function to use as an input for the average() function

```
function addition()
    {
        let numOne, numTwo, numThree, sum;
        numOne = parseInt(document.getElementById("firstNumber").value);
        numTwo = parseInt(document.getElementById("secondNumber").value);
        numThree = parseInt(document.getElementById("thirdNumber").value);
        sum = numOne + numTwo + numThree;
        document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sum;
        return sum; //this will be used as input for average
    }
```

// Function for average

```
    function average()
    {
        let sum = addition()
        avg = sum/3;
        document.getElementById("average").innerHTML = avg;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I'll try running this.Peace ✌️

Comment: if this answer helped to solve your problem, consider accepting my answer as the correct answer, it'd help me a lot!